# Entity Framework Add Fields to Dataset

Tags: entity-framework

Is it possible select only specific fields to return. In these example all `Tickets` including `Username`.
LazyLoading is disabled.

```
[Table("UserProfile")]
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastOnline { get; set; }

    public Tickets Tickets { get; set; }
}
```

Code

```
var whereQuery= "x => true";
_uow.Users.DbSet.Include("Tickets").Where(whereQuery).OnlyTickets.IncludeUsername();
//or
var whereQuery= "x => true";
_uow.Tickets.DbSet.Include("UserProfile").Where(whereQuery).OnlyTickets.IncludeUsername();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
_uow.Users.DbSet.Where(whereQuery).Select(u => new {Tickets = u.Tickets, Username = u.UserName});
```

You might add there Include(item => item.Tickets) to eager load Tickets prperty but this is not mandatory. If you do not want to use anonymous type you might use Tuple:

```
_uow.Users.DbSet.Where(whereQuery).Select(u => new Tuple<List<Ticket>,string>(u.Tickets, u.UserName));
```